# multiple node values all point to the same value even when using malloc and strcpy

Tags: c, pointers, nodes

Edit: just trying to learn C and coming from a Python background, hopefully I don't get downvoted too much for this.

I have this struct:

```
struct TreeNode {
    char *value;
    struct TreeNode *sibling;
    struct TreeNode *child;
};
```

I have this code to create nodes:

```
struct TreeNode* create_node(const char* value) {
    struct TreeNode node;
    node.value = malloc(sizeof(char) * (strlen(value) + 1));
    strcpy(node.value, value);
    node.sibling = NULL;
    node.child = NULL;
    struct TreeNode* node_ptr = &node;
    return node_ptr;
}
```

and this is the code in another function which creates the node (where values is an array of strings):

```
struct TreeNode a = create_node(values[0]);
struct TreeNode b = create_node(values[1]);
struct TreeNode c = create_node(values[2]);
struct TreeNode d = create_node(values[3]);
printf("%s\n", a->value);
printf("%s\n", b->value);
printf("%s\n", c->value);
printf("%s\n", d->value);
```

When I compile and run this, it prints `values[3]` four times (meaning the value for node a, b, c and d are all `values[3]`).

Question 1) Why do they all have the same value?

Note: Code which works properly is:

```
struct TreeNode* create_node(const char* value) {
    struct TreeNode* node = malloc(sizeof(struct TreeNode));
    node->value = malloc(strlen(value) + 1);
    strcpy(node->value, value);
    node->child = NULL;
    node->sibling = NULL;
    return node;
}
```

Question 2) Why does the latter work, and the former doesn't?

Question 3) In the latter, shouldn't it be `node->value = malloc(sizeof(char) * (strlen(value) + 1));` rather than just `node->value = malloc(strlen(value) + 1);`?

Comment: 'struct TreeNode node;' - local var, and you return a pointer to it:(

Comment: `printf("&s\n"` that can't be!!

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Typo, it was `%s` not `$s`.

Comment: A general suggestion: replace `malloc()`/`strcpy()` sequences with calls to `strdup()`.

Comment: Typo?  Always copy/paste the exact code you tested, even if it seems quicker to type it in again:(

Comment: `sizeof (char)` is 1 by definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 2) Why does the latter work, and the former doesn't?

Becouse you are returning address of local variable. In the time you are dereferencing pointer is the local variable out of scope (ended it's lifetime) which leads to [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). In function you have to return pointer only to variable(declared in function) with *dynamic storage duration*.

---

> 3) In the latter, shouldn't it be node->value = malloc(sizeof(char) *
>   (strlen(value) + 1)); rather than just node->value =
>   malloc(strlen(value) + 1);

Size of `char` is `1B` by standard.

**C99, section 6.5.3.4**

> When applied to an operand that has type char, unsigned char, or
>   signed char, (or a qualified version thereof) the result is 1.

---

> 1) Why do they all have the same value?

Becouse `UB`, change `create_node` to:

```
struct TreeNode* create_node(const char* value)
{
    struct TreeNode * node = (struct TreeNode*)malloc (sizeof(struct TreeNode));
    node->value = malloc(sizeof(char) * (strlen(value) + 1));
    strcpy(node->value, value);
    node->sibling = NULL;
    node->child = NULL;
    return node;
}
```

and it won't :-)

Comment: Okay thanks. I made this reply to another answer, but I'll ask it again here (just learning C so questions are basic). In the latter code, when doing `struct TreeNode* node = malloc(sizeof(struct TreeNode));`, node is just pointing to a block of memory the size of a TreeNode, right? At what point in the code does node become an actual tree node? Because two lines down, `node->child = NULL;` is there, so the block of memory has a child / became an actual struct node.

Comment: By calling `malloc(sizeof(struct TreeNode));` system will get you enough space for `sizeof(char *)` + `2*(sizeof(struct TreeNode*))` + `padding`, and you are storing an address of this block into pointer to struct variable. By dereferencing you can get on each variable in struct and set it. `node->child = NULL;` means that to that 8 or 4 Bytes for pointer is stored NULL, otherwise there would be stored address of another node if you have done `node->child = &anotherNode;` Hope you understand now @user2719875 :-)

Answer (score 2):

```
struct TreeNode* create_node(const char* value) {
    struct TreeNode node;
    node.value = malloc(sizeof(char) * (strlen(value) + 1));
    strcpy(node.value, value);
    node.sibling = NULL;
    node.child = NULL;
    struct TreeNode* node_ptr = &node;
    return node_ptr;
}
```

The struct `node` is local to this function, so it ceases to exist when the function returns. But you return a pointer to it. What is the caller supposed to do with a pointer to an object that no longer exists?

Comment: Oh, so it will result in undefined behavior? Then shouldn't a, b, c and d be null or some junk, or return an error? What causes a, b, c and d's value to all equal node d's value?

Comment: Undefined behavior means you can't expect any particular behavior.

Comment: Node d's value is junk when you're expecting node a's value, node b's value, or node c's value. It's likely that the implementation just happened to re-use the same address.

Comment: @user2719875 'd' was the last one you created.  The UB mainifested, in this case, as all four instances 'overlaying', and so all the four pointers pointing at the same, last instance, which happened to still be lying around under the stack pointer.  Tomorrow, it's nasal demons..

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Okay got it, so that is why the latter code works (it allocates memory on the heap and returns pointer to that). I'm just learning C, so my questions are a bit basic, but in the latter code, when doing `struct TreeNode* node = malloc(sizeof(struct TreeNode));`, node is just pointing to a block of memory the size of a TreeNode, right? At what point in the code does node become and actual tree node? Because two lines down, `node->child = NULL;` is there, so the block of memory has a child / became an actual struct node.

Comment: What is the difference between "an actual TreeNode" and "a block of memory the size of a TreeNode"?